# making combinations of data in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have two tables. First one contains first names, second one contains last names. (I could do it with one table with two columnes, but I'm using this way for other reason)

I want to make all possible combinations.

So if there are first names: John, Zed, Marko, and last names: Abbot, Zang I would like to get output like:
JohnAbbot
JohnZagn
ZedAbbot
ZedZang
MarkoAbbot
MarkoZang

I did something similar with For loop and alfanumeric signs. I was able to do it with 6 nested for loops, but I can't get this to work with while loop.

this is the code I use:

```
$query_name = "SELECT name FROM names";
$results=mysqli_query($connect, $query_name);
$query_surname = "SELECT surname FROM surnames";
$results2=mysqli_query($connect, $query_surname);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2)) {
        echo $row['name'].$row2['surname']."<br/>";
    }
}
```

with this I got only combinations with 1 name and all surnames.

after I added one more echo in first while loop like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    echo $row['name']."<br/>";

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results2)) {
        echo $row['name'].$row2['surname']."<br/>";
    }
}
```

with this I got:
first name from names table
combinations with first name and all last names (surnames)
all others names

I did not get all the combinations with all names and surnames.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because fetching is only done once per handle, so when your inner loop reaches the end of records, it will never go back to the first one - as you would need it to - but stay at the end and return false.

If your result sets are not million-row ones, try fetching both only once, then combine the arrays and foreach-loops which will obediently start from the beginning each time:

```
$a1 = array();while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) $a1[]=$row;
$a2 = array();while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) $a2[]=$row;

foreach($a1 as $row1) {
    foreach($a2 as $row2) {
        echo $row1['name'].$row2['surname']."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 1000 surnames and more than 5k names but it is working. Script is still running... but it get results as I wanted. Thanks

Comment: I'm saving combinations in other table. When I run script it is working fine, but after some time it get 500 Internal Server Error. The script made 129024 records and stopped. I have some other generator that uses FOR loop  http://testnadomena.xyz/emailovi/email_generator_samo_kombinacije.php
in that generator I use 6 counters for each loop and counter thet  set how many times it can run until server gets an error.  At the end of the page it displays me the number of each counter. So next time I just set counters to where it stopped last time. Is it possible to do that in this case?

Comment: Lazy solution: run a counter in the innermost loop to count the steps you've already taken before; if($skipLoops-->0) continue; this way, if you set $skipLoops to a million, it will only start generating at the millionth iteration.

Comment: A much better solution: use for(...) loops and remember the last iteration counter in the outer one. A for-loop can start wherever you want it to.

Comment: I would like to use FOR loop because I can manipulate it easier than WHILE loop, but I just can't get my code to work with FOR loop. any advice?

Comment: Show me what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to do next: get all the names from 1st table in array, get all the surnames from 2nd table in another array. Run FOR loop inside for loop to get combinations and save them in 3rd table. If I could use For loop I would be able to put counter and stop loops at number 100.000. Than I would print $i and $j (loop counters) to set it up for next run: 100.001 - 200.000. It sounds do easy but I just cant get data from tables and run it in FOR loops. I was only able to do it with WHILE loop. I dont know why...tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a simple query

```
select a.name, b.surname
from  names as a
FULL JOIN surnames as b
```